# template_preprocess_foo(&variables) flow

Tags: theming

I am trying to comprehend the data flow in a module.
The page is rendered with

```
template_preprocess_foo(&vars);
```

Can someone explain how to detect where the vars variable is initialized and in general to the overview of the data flow.

Comment: Have a look at [Settings up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)](http://drupal.org/node/223430), you should be able to extract everything you need to know from looking at that page and playing with some code

Comment: you can try get_defined_vars(), get_class_vars()